# Classify arrays of numbers based on distrebution Accord.net

Tags: c#, accord.net

Im using Accord.net in c# and there are many classifier algorithms in this library , i want to know what is the best for my case,
Im trying to classify with a supervised learning an arrays of double type according to their distrebution, for example :

learning set:

```
a1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4} label a
a2 = new int[]{1,2,5,6} label a
a3= new int[]{1,1,0,0} label b
a4=new int[]{1,0,0,0} label b
a5 =new int[]{-10,0,-10,0} label c
a6=new int[]{-20,1,-20,1} label c
```

and after learning the training set the classifier will need to recognize an array wich is not in the learning set:
for example:

```
classify(new int[]{1,1,1,0}) ---> returns label b
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your arrays have a fixed size? For example, do they always contains 4 entries like in your example?

If so, use a MulticlassSupportVectorMachine from Accord.NET. The [documentation page for MulticlassSupportVectorMachine](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_VectorMachines_MulticlassSupportVectorMachine.htm) has a simple example now how to classify arrays of size 3, but you can change it to your needs:

```
// Sample input data
double[][] inputs =
{
    new double[] { -1, 3, 2 },
    new double[] { -1, 3, 2 },
    new double[] { -1, 3, 2 },
    new double[] { 10, 82, 4 },
    new double[] { 10, 15, 4 },
    new double[] { 0, 0, 1 },
    new double[] { 0, 0, 2 },
};

// Output for each of the inputs
int[] outputs = { 0, 3, 1, 2 };


// Create a new polynomial kernel
IKernel kernel = new Polynomial(2);

// Create a new Multi-class Support Vector Machine with one input,
//  using the linear kernel and for four disjoint classes.
var machine = new MulticlassSupportVectorMachine(inputs: 3, kernel: kernel, classes: 4);

// Create the Multi-class learning algorithm for the machine
var teacher = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning(machine, inputs, outputs);

// Configure the learning algorithm to use SMO to train the
//  underlying SVMs in each of the binary class subproblems.
teacher.Algorithm = (svm, classInputs, classOutputs, i, j) =>
    new SequentialMinimalOptimization(svm, classInputs, classOutputs);

// Run the learning algorithm
double error = teacher.Run(); // output should be 0

// Compute the decision output for one of the input vectors
int decision = machine.Compute( new double[] { -1, 3, 2 });
```

Comment: Did you try with other kernels? How many samples do you have, and what are their dimensions?

Comment: Yes i tried with all the types of kernels ,i have two sets for the first the dimension is 16 and the other is 32

Comment: Can it be that you didn't have enough training data? Was the example you posted actually containing all the data you had?